# M2.4.1 Unable to resolve source file jquery\fileUploader\fileupload-fp.js

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.1

I'm getting issue with the file uploader in the backend admin of M2.4.1 It is missing file below and can see a 404 for the file in the browser console. I have cleared static content, generated folder and var\view_preprocessed folders. Run setup:upgrade, compile commands and forced rebuild of static content. Not sure what else to try ... Any suggestions.?? Everything else seems to be working fine...  just this..

adminhtmlMagento\backend\en_GB\jquery\fileUploader\fileupload-fp.js

Comment: Seems to be a bug. The following helps in my case: cp -r vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/jquery/fileUploader pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery/

Answer (score 4):

I updated the revolution slider extension but still facing the same issue. Further searching "jquery/file-uploader" within code found it was still referenced to "jquery.fileupload-fp". Hence changed it from

"jquery/file-uploader": "jquery/fileUploader/jquery.fileupload-fp",

to

'jquery/file-uploader': 'jquery/fileUploader/jquery.fileuploader',

and issue was fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I found that fileupload-fp.js was no longer in Magento 2.4 (coming from 2.3.5-p2). After looking at who was referencing it, I found that my Revolution Slider extension was the culprit. Updating that extension resolved this for me.

In short, check your **`pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs-config.js`** and see who is referencing fileupload-fp.js. Then go from there.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with similar problem but not from the same extension problem, you can search for text`jquery.fileupload-fp` in the magento root folder including *.gitignore* ignored files (with IDE or tools like `ack` or `ag`) and fix the file

Editing pub/static would be reset upon redeploying static. One of the problem can be found in this file `vendor/magento/module-user/view/adminhtml/web/app-config.js`

In older release of magento it still requires `jquery.fileupload-fp` instead of `jquery.fileupload`.

So we can edit that file `vendor/magento/module-user/view/adminhtml/web/app-config.js` (or upgrade the magento version and vendor folder).

Something like:

```
...
'paths': {
    'jquery/ui': 'jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.2',
    'jquery/validate': 'jquery/jquery.validate',
    'jquery/hover-intent': 'jquery/jquery.hoverIntent',
    'jquery/file-uploader': 'jquery/fileUploader/jquery.fileupload-fp',
    'prototype': 'prototype/prototype-amd',
    'text': 'requirejs/text',
    'domReady': 'requirejs/domReady',
    'ko': 'ko/ko'
}
...
```

to

```
...
'paths': {
    'jquery/ui': 'jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.2',
    'jquery/validate': 'jquery/jquery.validate',
    'jquery/hover-intent': 'jquery/jquery.hoverIntent',
    'jquery/file-uploader': 'jquery/fileUploader/jquery.fileupload',
    'prototype': 'prototype/prototype-amd',
    'text': 'requirejs/text',
    'domReady': 'requirejs/domReady',
    'ko': 'ko/ko'
}
...
```

There could be other files having this bug, so use the text search I mentioned earlier